# Connecting between existing .db to Postgres using pgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Completely new to SQL.
I've created a db in Python using SQLAlchemy, now I want to connect/import it to postgres, using pgAdmin III.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres can restore databases from file by pg_restore. It can handle files that is just a sequence of sql commands. And question - you want to import it to use postgre with sqlalchemy or without?